# Why does the use() method still executed after get() has handled a request successfully in express.js?

Tags: express, routes

I have this express.js code:

```
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('homePage', { title: 'Express' });
    });

    app.use((req, res) => {
        console.log('use() is executed');
        res.end();
    });
```

If the request is handled by the `get()` method, `use()` is not supposed to execute. But I noticed that it still execute even though everything was fine and the page is rendered. Did I do something wrong or did I miss something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Express Doc:
Link: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use
`app.use([path,] callback [, callback...])`
Mounts the specified middleware function or functions at the specified path: the middleware function is executed when the base of the requested path matches the path.

`app.use()` register the function as middleware, and you didn't specify the path. That's why it will run every time when any route is called.
The placement of the middlewares will change the execution order. However,  they don't change the fact that the middleware will be executed as, well middlewares, which will be executed before the actual functions with in the routes.

Comment: Yes but it's not supposed to catch the `'\'` route because it's already handled by `app.get()`

Comment: Some of the middleware that will act on the route is actually registered after the code of the actual route so it has access to all the route's properties. As long as it is a middleware. It will get executed when the routes are called. I have updated my answer a bit.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Thanks a lot.